# Nested for() in c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

No matter how I see this problem, I keep getting the answer to be 10. When I run the program, the answer gives me 20. I am lost as to how this should be solved. Could anyone help me with much detail? Thanks! ps. first programming class in c++.

```
int n = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      n = n + j;
```

Comment: Step through the code, line by line, in a debugger, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: By the way, the last iteration alone of the outer loop will by itself add `10` (`0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4`) to `n`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the advice on monitoring the variables. I will definitely use that. And thanks for your knowledge!

Comment: Change the `<=` in the outer loop to `<` and the result will be `10`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see n after each iteration of i.
n = prev value of n + sum of 0 to i-1;

```
i=1 , n= 0
i=2 , n= 0+0+1=1
i=3, n= 1+0+1+2 =4
i=4, n= 4+0+1+2+3=10
i=5, n= 10+0+1+2+3+4 =20
```

Answer (score 2):

When `i == 1` you add `0` to `n`, so `n == 0`.

When `i == 2` you add `0` and `1` to `n`, so `n == 0 + 0 + 1 == 1`.

When `i == 3` you add `0`, `1`, `2` to `n`, so `n == 1 + 0 + 1 + 2 == 4`.

When `i == 4` you add `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` to `n`, so `n == 4 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 == 10`.

When `i == 5` you add `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` to `n`, so `n = 10 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 == 20`

If you only got 10, you either missed the last iteration of the outer loop (because `10` is the result after 4 iterations), or you forgot that you're adding on to what you accumulated in the previous iterations (since the last iteration adds `10` to the total).

Comment: Thanks Barmar! So, the inner loop increases from 0 to i, then gets added to n? Now i see! Thank you for this visual help

Comment: What do you think `n = n + j` does? Did you think `n` would get set back to `0` each time through the outer loop?

Comment: this was my thought.

i=1, n=0
i=2, n=0+1
i=3, n=1+2
i=4, n=3+3
i=5, n=6+4 =10

so, i didnt loop from 0 to i which kept making me get 10.

Comment: Things don't happen by themselves. If you want to set `n` back to `0` each time, you need to put `n = 0;` in the loop. In your code it only happens before the outer loop, not every time.